# Change of column names after concat()

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dfs:

```
df1
   a  b 
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

```
df2
   c  d 
0  5  4
1  2  3
```

After concat, I get werid column names:

```
[In:]
df3=pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

[Out:]
   a  b  (c,) (d,)
0  1  2  5     4
1  3  4  2     3
```

df2 has had tuples in its columns before, maybe that's the reason.
If I try to get the dtypes, I get int64 for all columns.

If I just had to rename the columns, it would not be any problem, but it seems like operating with these columns brings up a problem with the dimension of these columns.

Does anyone understand the issue?

Comment: check df2.columns if they are tuples to begin with

Comment: I can't reproduce it with: `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 3], 'b':[2, 4]}) `  and
`df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c':[5, 2], 'd':[4, 3]})`

Comment: it says :MultiIndex(levels=[[ 'c', 'd']],
 labels=[[0, 1]])

Comment: that might be the problem, right? It should be Index and not Multiindex?

Comment: how can I convert that?

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten the column index list using list comprehension:

```
df3.columns = [x for t in df3.columns.to_list() for x in t]
```

Example:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 3], 'b':[2, 4]})
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame([[5, 4],[2, 3]], columns = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[ 'c', 'd']], codes=[[0, 1]]))
>>> df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
>>> df3
   a  b  (c,)  (d,)
0  1  2     5     4
1  3  4     2     3
>>> df3.columns = [x for t in df3.columns.to_list() for x in t]
>>> df3
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  5  4
1  3  4  2  3
```

Answer (score 1):

Flatten your column headers:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 3], 'b':[2, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[5, 4],[2, 3]], columns = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[ 'c', 'd']], codes=[[0, 1]]))
df2.columns = df2.columns.map(''.join)
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
df3
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  5  4
1  3  4  2  3
```